# PHP page is giving me error but I can't find the error

Tags: php, joomla, syntax-error, helix

```
"<?php echo //$this->helix3->bodyClass($body_classes); ?> off-canvas-menu-init"
```

Hey guys, I'm struggling to find the mistake on this one, please give man a hand.

Comment: Why are you commenting out the rest of the line? Where is the comment supposed to end? what is this supposed to echo? And you do realise that the `?>` will actually terminate the comment leaving invalid PHP syntax?

Comment: Check your PHP logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of code should be in the index.php of your default template. Open that, find the line and move the comment // before the echo.

Comment: thanks, that's actually part of a <body class="codeThatIPosted"> cheers, that answers my question